# HTML CSS Border

Tags: css

I am trying to create a border that surrounds the text of a title:

```
#headerwrap h1 {
    border: 5px solid red;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Patua One', cursive;
    font-size: 4em;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 1em 0em 3em 0em;
}
```

The problem is the border is spanning the whole width of the page instead of just the text. I have experimented with `display: inline-block;` But that makes the border too close to the text.

Is there a way to make the border around the text, and with a custom outset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to `inline-block`, add some padding:

```
padding: 0.1em 0.1em
```

Comment: My friend, I have been looking for this for a very long time. Thankyou!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @user3361034, to the extent either of these answers addresses your question, please consider marking one of them as answered.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sure just use inline-block and give it some padding.

Answer (score 0):

Just use inline-block and add some padding along side with it :)
Just like this
padding: 0.11em 0.1em
UPDATE:
Sorry, I messed up. 
THIS is how its done:
padding: 0.1em 0.1em
Do it any size, but just make sure both are the same size.